# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Saludos, estoy actualizando una tabla llamada tbl_articulos usando la misma vista donde la Primary key = idArticulo, el insert me realiza de manera impecable el problema es cuando quiero actualizar me genera el error ESTOY TRABAJANDO CON LARAVEL 5.3

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 770:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where 
clause' (SQL: update `tbl_articulo` set `idArticulo` = 7, `descripcion` = 
CASACA DAMA 222, `modelo` = CORTE PRINCESA, `detalleAdicional` = CASACA DAMA 
2222, `habilitado` = 1, `idCategoria` = 2, `idColor` = 1, `updated_at` = 
2017-05-23 03:30:42 where `id` is null)
```

Me dice que no la clave id es nula pero mi primary key es idArticulo. Gracias por su ayuda. muy agradecido me despido.

Este es mi repositorio

```
<?php
namespace App\Repository;
use App\Articulo;
class ArticuloRepository 
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'idArticulo';

    Public function guardar($data){
      $Articulo = new articulo();

      //logica para ver si es un UPDATE
      if ($data['idArticulo'] > 0) 
      {
        $Articulo->exists = true;
        $Articulo->idArticulo = $data['idArticulo'];
      }

      $Articulo->descripcion      = $data['descripcion'];
      $Articulo->modelo           = $data['modelo'];
      $Articulo->detalleAdicional = $data['detalleAdicional'];
      $Articulo->habilitado       = $data['habilitado'];
      $Articulo->idCategoria      = $data['idCategoria'];
      $Articulo->idColor          = $data['idColor'];

      $Articulo->save();
    }
}
```

Este es mi controlador

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Repository\ArticuloRepository;

class ArticuloController extends Controller{

    private $ArticuloRepo;
    public function store(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request,[
            'descripcion' => 'required|min:4',
            'modelo' => 'required|min:4',
            'idCategoria' => 'required|integer',
            'idColor' => 'required|integer',
            'habilitado' => 'required|integer',
            'detalleAdicional' => 'required',
            ]);
        $this->ArticuloRepo->guardar($request);
        return redirect('articulo');
    }

    public function create($idArticulo = 0){
        return view('articulo/create',
        ['model'=>($idArticulo > 0 ? $this->ArticuloRepo->obtener($idArticulo):null) ]);

    }

    public function edit($idArticulo = 0){
        return view('articulo/create',
        ['model'=>($idArticulo > 0 ? $this->ArticuloRepo->obtener($idArticulo):null) ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo que el error te está diciendo es que la `tbl_articulo` **no tiene ninguna columna llamada `id`**. ¿Existe realmente una columna llamada `id` en dicha tabla o la estás confundiendo con la columna `idArticulo`?

Comment: lo mas recomendables  es que toda las llaves primaria sea id y no idArticulos, ya que va a tener mas trabajo cambiando la llave primaria en toda las tablas y corresponde a un protocolo de trabajo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aunque no vemos el código de la clase `articulo`, al parecer no estás diciéndole a esta que su clave primaria es `idArticulo` como lo estás haciendo en la clase `ArticuloRepository`.

Asumiendo que tu clase `articulo` siga la sintaxis básica de Laravel para los modelos, deberías tener algo así en dicha clase:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Articulo extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'tbl_articulo';

    protected $primaryKey = 'idArticulo';

    // etc...

}
```

Más información en la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#defining-models

Comment: Gracias amigo me sirvio de mucho tu respuesta